# Vagrant not up and stuck there without any error message

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

The environment is Windows 7 64 bit ultimate. vutual box 5.1.22 installed. Vagrant 1.9.7 is installed and.net framework 4.5 and microsoft c++ redistributable 2010 and 2012 are installed.

```
vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
```

Both command above are successful!

Then, nightmare happened.
vagrant up
is stuck. No any error message displays in screen. It just stuck there.
Are there anybody know this software. Is this vagrant always not stable like this? It is so unfriendly, and no any error message to pop out.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar experience with Vagrant 1.9.7 and VirtualBox 5.1.26 on Windows 7 x64.

Run `vagrant up --debug` to see detailed output of the process. It gets hung at some point. For me it was at `STDOUT TRUE`.

The solution that worked for me was to start the `vagrant_up --debug`, then at the point when it gets stuck, open task manager processes, and kill the `powershell.exe` process. I had to do this each time it got stuck.

Another alternative is to upgrade PowerShell to version 5, using the Windows Management Framework 5.

Last resort is to downgrade to Vagrant 1.9.6, which works as expected.

There is an open Github issue with (possibly) additional detail:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8783